# I want to extract an unique resource information from DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to extract the all information(`?s ?p ?o`) of movie "The Shawshank Redemption" ,the SPARQL that I wrote is:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE
{
  ?s ?p ?o
  filter regex(?s,'The_Shawshank_Redemption').
}
```

But it only tured out a few result with the property rdfs:type.
I want all the properties of the movie,how can I do it?
The result was:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?p ?o
WHERE
{
  dbr:The_Shawshank_Redemption ?p ?o.
}
```

If you also want the information for the soundtrack and the angola3, just query them in the same pattern like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Options abound.  The simplest is --

```
PREFIX  dbr:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
DESCRIBE  dbr:The_Shawshank_Redemption
```

You might also take a look at [iSPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/), the visual SPARQL query builder also available on the DBpedia host instance.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives you all the properties related to the movie:

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT Distinct ?p 
WHERE
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Shawshank_Redemption> ?p ?o.
}
```